# Is it possible to run a Visual Studio for Mac project on Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-mac

Can a project made in Visual Studio for Mac be opened and run in Visual Studio on Windows?
I only have access to Mac, so unfortunately I cannot check it by myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the framework and libraries you target.  Obviously if you use MonoMac or something with a Mac-specific UI, it'll run only on the Mac, but if you're writing a console app targeting .NET Core, by default it'll run fine on Windows.  To write a cross-platform UI, you could try a third-party framework like Avalonia.

Edit: I should add that the .csproj and .sln formats used by Visual Studio for Mac are the same used by VS for Windows, so in general a project or solution for a cross-platform app (.NET Core) or library (.NET Core or .NET Standard) can be read by either Visual Studio.

In fact, I run Parallels with Windows 10 on my Mac with my repos in shared folders and will compile my cross-platform apps from whichever side on which I wish to run them.  (There are line-ending considerations and other minor annoyances, but it works.)

Comment: Say I have a Razor Pages web app I've built on Windows in VS and I want a designer who uses Mac to open and work on styling the pages with VS for Mac. Is that a workable solution?